# VBA String Match with a For Loop and StrComp

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use a for loop to change a cell in a column to "truck" if the conditions are met.

With the code below, some rows are going through the loop incorrectly.
For instance: Lets say Milwaukee is the departure city, and Doral is the Arrival, it will still put in a "truck" in column 13.

Can anyone offer direction on how to fix?

```
Sub VBAtest()

'Declare Variables
Dim Departure As Integer
Dim Arrival As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim k As Long

'Initialize Variables
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Departure = 4
Arrival = 8    

'Count Rows and Store in Variable
k = sh.Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

'For Loop that is putting "Truck" in the wrong places
For row = 2 To k
    If StrComp(Cells(Arrival, row), "Doral") = 1 Then
        If StrComp(Cells(Departure, row), "Albany") = 1 Then
            Cells(row, 13) = "truck"
        End If
    End If
Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: Your strcomp cells are backward, they should be `(row,Arrival)` and `(row,Departure)`

Comment: Agree with @Scott Craner, but your `k` value is also wrong. This is deriving the number of rows in the range "A1:A[end]" but you're starting the comparison from row 2 so you're checking empty rows at the bottom. Change that line to: `k = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`